# Left/Right Thumbnails with Center Active Image - Slick

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I have been trying for few days already to do something like:
[Sample Image][1]

This would be an infinite slider with a center image. The 2 images on Left/Right would be cropped.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygwc1.jpg

The best result I got so far wasnt really good. Its kinda jumpy and buggy so if you could give me a hand, I would really appreciate it :)

My Code is something like this:

```js
    $(".mySlider").slick({
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      infinite: true,
      centerMode: true,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      variableWidth: true,
    });
```

```css
.slick-slide img {
  width: 178px;
  height: 450px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active.slick-center img {
  width: 278px;
  height: 450px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="mySlider">
    <div><img src="https://test.noxaddons.com/img/img-1.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://test.noxaddons.com/img/img-2.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://test.noxaddons.com/img/img-3.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://test.noxaddons.com/img/img-4.jpg" /></div>
    <div><img src="https://test.noxaddons.com/img/img-5.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you'll need to use the `beforeChange` event to add/remove classes for images sizes so that sizing of the center image takes place before the slide animation starts.